# How can you create an Array that has is modifiable to a set amount in a constructor?

Tags: arrays, constructor, linked-list

I have been working on a game of tic tac toe for a very long while and I have it running very well, however I wanted to take it to the next level, that being that I wanted to make it a modifiable board to a size set by user input.

Here is a bit of the code I have now:

```
            import java.util.*;

            public class board {

//************** INSTANCE VARIABLES ****************

private String[][] space = new String[3][3];
private String player1 = "";
private String player2 = "";
private int turnNum = 0;
private int playerCount = 0;
private boolean newGame = true;
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//************** CONSTRUCTOR ****************

/**
 * Constructs a board with 9 spaces all set to the default value of space
 */
public board(){
    for (int i = 0; i<=2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<=2; j++){
            this.setSpace(i, j, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor for board is what I want to modify, I am trying to get it to create a board to a set variable in the arguments for the constructor

Thanks!

P.S. I was told that it had something to do with linked lists, but I have no idea how to use and implement them :/

Answer (score 1):

Don't define the size of the string 2D array 'space' in the declaration.
Assign the size after get the size from user.

you can call the function createBoard in the constructor. Lets try it.

```
private String[][] space;
private String player1 = "";
private String player2 = "";
private int turnNum = 0;
private int playerCount = 0;
private boolean newGame = true;
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

public void createBoard(){
    //get board width
    System.out.print("Enter board width:");
    int width = input.nextInt();

    //get board height 
    System.out.print("Enter board height:");
    int height = input.nextInt();

    //allocate space
    space = new String[height][width];
    board(width, height);

}

public void board(int width, int height){
    for (int i = 0; i< height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< width; j++){
            this.setSpace(i, j, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves all of my problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public board(int width, int height){
    for (int i = 0; i<=width; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<=height; j++){
            this.setSpace(i, j, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

But make sure to have some default values set.

You have declared

```
private String[][] space = new String[3][3];
```

And you will have to replace the [3][3] because you don't know during compile time what you want the size to be. Instead of a 2-D array you can use a data structure.

You can choose a number of ways to do this. One way is to have an ArrayList (you will have to import this package) of strings and use the ArrayList api to dynamically add strings of some size. So for example you would add a string of size "length" n times where n is the "width". You could have a linked list of spaces if you like too.

Hope this kind of helps!